# Using a http://192.168 address for a local laravel rest API

Tags: laravel, rest, http, laravel-8, laravel-7

Im upgrading from laravel 7 to laravel 8 and Im trying to make a http request to a laravel API hosted locally. If I use http://localhost or http://127.0.0.1, the requests give a response. But if I use a http://192.168.x.x address, I get an error `Error: connect ECONNREFUSED`. How do I use http://192.168.x.x ?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/98Z1r.png

Comment: Check your OS firewall settings (each OS has a different way to do this). Also check your webserver settings. By default most webservers block non local connections until you configure them to not do that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Access Laravel project over a network using IP](https://themanish.com/access-laravel-project-over-a-network-using-ip/)

1- Identify your IP Address

on windows
ipconfig

on linux
ifconfig

2-Run your project
php artisan serve --host=192.168.1.10 --port=8000

3-Access your project via browser (on remote)

http://192.168.1.10:8000

Possible Issues:

If your firewall is enabled, remote system might me blocked access.
– for this, you can either disable firewall completey on your local system
– or, enable certain port
In linux to allow a port

ufw status
ufw enable 8000